# Finding homomorphisms in normal groups to $S_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism

This question is related to my trouble in abstract algebra in general so some general advice is really appreciated!! (I'm really new to this.)

Let A be an infinite subset of G with $n = \#A$. 
\begin{equation}
H = \{g∈G: gag^{-1}∈A, \forall a∈A\}\\
N = \{g∈G: ga=ag, \forall a∈A \}
\end{equation}

First I'm asked to prove that H is a subgroup of G. No problem. first I use a=g to prove that H isn't empty, then I fix a and take g and g'. 
Second I'm asked to prove that N is a normal subgroup of H. Now I have to show that any left coset $hN=Nh$ with h in H. (my first complication)

And in the end I have to find a homomorphism $\,f:H \to S_n$ so that $N=Ker(f)$.
Now with this one I have no idea how to even begin.

Comment: "Let $A$ be an infinite subset of $G$ with $n=\#A$." Usually, we only use $n$ to stand for finite quantities, not infinite ones. Did you mean to write something different?

Comment: Also, does $G$ have anything to do with $S_n$?

Comment: @GerryMyerson He means that $A$ is a subgroup of $G$(might be a mistake on his part). You can see this in his "proof" that $H$ is a subgroup("use $a=g$ to prove that H isn't empty"). Which only makes sense if $A$ is a subgroup. As for the $n=\#A$ thing, I am guessing that it means cosets. But I could be wrong.

Comment: Are you still here, Jay?

Comment: Hey @GerryMyerson, yes I am. This whole problem was a mistake of the professor's part and it's substituted by another problem. So I'm just going to assume 'Let A be an infinite subset of GG with n=#An=#A.' was a bad mess up.

Comment: OK, Jay. You might want to delete the question, then. Meanwhile, I'll vote to close it.